# how to customize the 403 error page in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView,ListView
from .models import Article
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

How can i customize the 404 error page?

Comment: What do you mean customize the 404 error page?

Comment: i mean i want to build my own colorful 403 page rather then default one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Many resources are decorated error pages if there is a failure in processing a request from the client.
Use this link https://evileg.com/en/post/9/

Comment: this link is for crsf_token but i want LoginRequiredMixin error custom page